# Legendre Conjecture - Counting prime numbers

Tags: python

Given an integer n, the function legendre_n should return the number of prime numbers between n^2 and (n+1)^2.

This is the code I wrote:

```
def legendre_n(n):
    """Returns the number of primes between n**2 and (n+1)**2"""
    count = 0
    for i in range(n**2, ((n+1)**2)):
        if i%2 != 0:
            count += 1
    return count
```

```
print(legendre_n(12)) = > 5 but I'm getting 12
print(legendre_n(3)) => 2 but I'm getting 4
```

After testing on python tutor, I found out that the condition I set (i%2 != 0) only filters out odd numbers. However, not all odd numbers are prime numbers. I understand that prime numbers should only be divisible by 1 and the number itself, but I'm stucked at setting the correct condition.

Comment: Instead of `i%2==0` you need a `is_prime(i)` logic, a Google search will yield that logic.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
def legendre_n(n):
    """Returns the number of primes between n**2 and (n+1)**2"""
    count = 0
    for num in range(n**2, ((n+1)**2)):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                count = num
    return count
```

you want to check either your `num` is `devidable` with any other number between 2 and itself (`modulo` calculation). If not, it is a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no known "fast" computation to determining if a number is prime. The only known methods involve loops of checks (see some of the other answers). This makes prime factorization a key component in cryptography.

The long story short, is that you must define a function like the ones mentioned above, or you must import one. For example, sympy.isprime() is a highly optimized function that probably runs much faster. Of course, if you are going to import the amazing number theory package, why not just do:

```
import sympy

def legendre_n(n):
    count = 0
    for _ in sympy.primerange(n**2,(n+1)**2+1):
        count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score -1):

You only need is make a identifier of prime numbers.
you can try this:

```
def isprime(n):
   for i in range(2,n):
      if(n%i)==0:return False
   return True

def legendre_n(n):
    """Returns the number of primes between n**2 and (n+1)**2"""
    count = 0
    for i in range(n**2, ((n+1)**2)):
        if isprime(i):
            count += 1
    return count
```